# Angular 7:TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angular7

```
this.db.object('/users/'+user.uid).update({
  name:user.displayName,email:user.email
  });
}
```

getting this error :

> ```
> core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'
>      at new FirebaseObjectObservable (firebase_object_observable.js:16)
>      at FirebaseObjectFactory (firebase_object_factory.js:7)
>      at AngularFireDatabase.push../node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.js.AngularFireDatabase.object (database.js:18)
>      at UserService.save (user.service.ts:20)
>      at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:23)
>      at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
>      at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
>      at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
>      at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>      at Notification.observe (Notification.js:20)
>  defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:9110
> ```

Comment: I suggest to change title, because it is not related to angulatlr, but Firebase and Typescript and RxJS

Answer (score 10):

Go to tsconfig.json,

Change the target from es2015 to es5.

This worked for me.

I think the compiler is still having issues when you use the AngularFire Database methods, I am not 100% sure of the cause, but changing the target solved the issue immediately and my user field was easily created in the DataBase

Comment: The solution works for me as well. Change the target and recompile the code using *ng serve*

Comment: What if I don't want to downgrade the target to es5?

Comment: @eli Brilliant question, however, you might have to find another fix for it then. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

change **TARGET** in `TSCONFIG.JSON` from **es2015** to **es5**
and then recompile with `ng serve`