# How to save users from Angular App to Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Currently ,i'm following a tutorial to learn Angular and i'm having some issues with saving the users in firebase database.The Database is empty even after logging-in.
Here's the code : 
First i created a service for users , that has a method to store the users using their UID of course  :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }
  save (user: firebase.User) {
    this.db.object('/users/'+user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    });
  }
}
```

and then i used this service in my app.component ...

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private userService: UserService,private auth: AuthService,router:Router)
  {
    auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
      if(user)
      {
        userService.save(user);
        let returnUrl=localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
        router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Note that the AuthService is working fine . and all the services all called as providers in the app.module

Edit : i just noticed this error in my console :

````
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new FirebaseObjectObservable (firebase_object_observable.js:16)
    at FirebaseObjectFactory (firebase_object_factory.js:7)
    at AngularFireDatabase.push../node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.js.AngularFireDatabase.object (database.js:18)

```
````

Comment: could you log the `user` parameter that is passed to the `save` method in the `userService`

Comment: @c_ogoo yes i can , i get all the information about the logged user ( i'm using Google Authentication , so i'm getting all the informations about my account )

Comment: @c_ogoo i found an error in the console , i edited my post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029413/angular-7typeerror-class-constructor-observable-cannot-be-invoked-without-new

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem , by editing tsconfig.json file :

For those who has the same error ,Change the target from es2015 to es5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029413/angular-7typeerror-class-constructor-observable-cannot-be-invoked-without-new